# calculation optimization on a CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am preparing data from several CSV files. One is like this:

```
userID,    createdAt,            collectedAt
6301,      2006-09-18 01:07:50,  2010-01-17 20:38:25
10836,     2006-10-27 14:38:04,  2010-06-18 03:35:34
10997,     2006-10-29 09:50:38,  2010-04-24 01:12:40
```

And another like:

```
userID,    seriesOfNumber
6301,      "3269,3310,3695,3732,3788,3872,3929,3893"
10836,     "1949,1963,1963,1963,1963,1963,1963,1962,1961,1961"
10997,     "1119,1119,999,999,1050,1170,1071,799,799,799,862,862,862,862"
```

I want to have a output.csv with all information from csv1 and standart deviation of the series from csv2.

Actually this is what I'm doing:

```py
import pandas as pd
import csv
import statistics

def days_between(d1, d2):
    d1 = datetime.strptime(d1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    d2 = datetime.strptime(d2, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    return abs((d2 - d1).days)

def stddev(id):
    with open('csvFile/csv1.csv', encoding="utf-8") as csv1:
        follow = csv.DictReader(csv1)
        for row in follow:
            if id == row["userID"]:
                return(statistics.stdev(list(map(int, row["seriesOfNumberOfFollowings"].split(","))))) #Split one line in array of str then transfort str array to int array

with open('csvFile/user.csv', encoding="utf-8") as user, open('output.csv', 'w') as output:

    user = csv.DictReader(user)

    writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(["accountLongevity", "standardDevidationFollowing"]) # write a header row

    for row in user:
        data = []
        data.append(days_between(row['createdAt'], row['collectedAt']))
        data.append(stddev(row['userID']))
        writer.writerow(data)
```

This actualy work. But take a very long time (I've more then 500 000 users). I think I can avoid to open csv1 at each row of user. I tried to pass my csv in parameter of my function but it's  work for my 1st. It's like the fuction never increment.
And here my problem is for 2 csv. Put my output it a summary of 4 csv.

Comment: Just curious why you did not use `pandas` while you must have known it as you added the tag. It will be very easy and fast to run the job via pandas. By the way, even you don't want to use pandas, putting everything in a list variable rather than continuously reading files will make it far quicker.

Comment: you should read all data at  once and calculate all standart deviations at once. Reading again and again from file is waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

As Zealseeker suggest I use pandas for reading my CSV files. Next I'm abble to merge on ID. Here the code:

```py
def legitimate():
    csv1 = pd.read_csv("csvFile/csv1.csvt", sep='\t', names=["userID", "createdAt", "collectedAt"])
    csv2 = pd.read_csv("csvFile/csv3.csv", sep='\t', names=["userID", "seriesOfNumberOfFollowings"])


    mergeCSV = pd.merge(csv1 , csv2, on="userID", how = "inner")
    mergeCSV ['class'] = 0

    for ind in mergeCSV .index:
        mergeCSV.at[ind, 'seriesOfNumberOfFollowings'] = stddev(mergeCSV ['seriesOfNumberOfFollowings'][ind])
        mergeCSV.at[ind, 'createdAt'] = days_between(mergeCSV ['createdAt'][ind], mergeCSV ['collectedAt'][ind])

    return mergeCSV
```

With this method I can merge more than 2 CSV pretty quickly